# Facebook share only share text (React)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, facebook, facebook-share

I am trying to simply share a block of text and not include any images-

```
onClick={() => {
                        window.FB.ui({
                            method: 'share',
                            // href: 'URL',
                            quote: 'Here is the quote with URL I am using',
                        }, function (response) {
                            if (response && !response.error_message) {
                                // then get post content
                                alert('successfully posted. Status id : '+response.post_id);
                            } else {
                                alert('Something went error.');
                            }
                         });
                    }}
```

If I exclude the URL then it just pops up with an empty share.  If I add in the URL then I get the quote, but I also get a box with the URL's picture and link.  Is there a way to completely hide/ not show that box.  I have tried using description and many other fields, but those don't show as well.

Update- I do see this in the docs in regards to href:

> The link attached to this post. Required when using method share.
>   Include open graph meta tags in the page at this URL to customize the
>   story that is shared.

Is there another method in facebook to just share text?

Comment: What text are you sharing?

Comment: Text includes URL and a promo code for our application (this was in the "quote").  Marketing didn't want there to be the box that you see/ just our block of text.

Comment: Just share a URL and have the user type what ever message they want.

Comment: Yeah I wanted a specific message put in.  Turns out my company is ok with an image now so I am just not worrying about the issue, but still have no solution to have a quote pasted without the box